# Rails 2.3.x - how does this ActiveRecord scope work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

There's a named_scope in a project I'm working on that looks like the following:

```
 # default product scope only lists available and non-deleted products
  ::Product.named_scope :active,      lambda { |*args|
    Product.not_deleted.available(args.first).scope(:find)
  }
```

The initial named_scope makes sense. The confusing part here is how .scope(:find) works. This is clearly calling another named scope (not_deleted), and applying .scope(:find) afterwards. What/how does .scope(:find) work here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick answer

```
Product.not_deleted.available(args.first)
```

is a named-scope itself, formed by combining both named scopes.

`scope(:find)` gets the conditions for a named-scope (or combination of scopes), which you can in turn use to create a new named-scope.

So by example:

```
named_scope :active,      :conditions => 'active  = true' 
named_scope :not_deleted, :conditions => 'deleted = false'
```

then you write

```
named_scope :active_and_not_deleted, :conditions => 'active = true and deleted = false'
```

or, you could write

```
named_scope :active_and_not_deleted, lambda { self.active.not_deleted.scope(:find) }
```

which is identical. I hope that makes it clear.

Note that this has become simpler (cleaner) in rails 3, you would just write

```
scope :active_and_not_deleted, active.not_deleted
```

Answer (score 2):

Scope is a method on ActiveRecord::Base that returns the current scope for the method passed in (what would actually be used to build the query if you were to run it at this moment).

```
# Retrieve the scope for the given method and optional key.
def scope(method, key = nil) #:nodoc:
  if current_scoped_methods && (scope = current_scoped_methods[method])
    key ? scope[key] : scope
  end
end
```

So in your example, the lambda returns the scope for a `Product.find` call after merging all the other named scopes.

I have a named_scope:

```
named_scope :active, {:conditions => {:active => true}}
```

In my console output, `Object.active.scope(:find)` returns:

```
{:conditions => {:active => true}}
```