# has_many order by model and another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Question model.
every question can have many answers. And answers have status id which is a number.

So: I have:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :answers, :order =>'status_cat_id'
```

Now, answers are related to users, and I want the order of answers to be first by status_is and then by user name.

So, when I'll call: @question.answers I will get the answers ordered first by status and then by the user name.

Is it possible to achieve that through the model?

Comment: `:order =>'status_cat_id,user_id'` should work

Comment: But user is another table!

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? and also what does the Answer model look like?

Comment: How is related users to answers?

Comment: @dmcnally - Rails 2.3.2, Ruby - 1.8.6. Answer has a user_id which connects it to the users table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
has_many :answers, :include => :user, :order =>'status_cat_id, users.name'
```

Comment: You can also use a [`named_scope`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4765365/877472) too if you like. That way you can safely call the `answers` association without the ordering and eager loading in situations that don't require it.